# Difference in connotation between "a statement" vs "a statement to make"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, connotation

I feel there is a difference between the sentences

> That sounds like a bold statement.

and

> That sounds like a bold statement to make.

I think they differ in connotation, but I could not describe the difference. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

I find that the difference between:

(1) That sounds like a bold statement.

and

(2) That sounds like a bold statement to make.

lies in the fact that in (1) the boldness is attributed to **the statement itself**, while in (2) it is attributed to **the making of the statement**. (1) is therefore more impersonal than (2). Even though the maker of the statement is not mentioned in (2), there is an implicit reference to him/her as the doer of the action. It can thus be understood that it was bold of him/her to make the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatical difference is:

> "A statement"

= a noun

> "A statement to make"

= a noun + infinitive phrase